# Wigner Function of Squeezed Vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, complex-numbers, squeezed-states

I am trying to figure out how to derive the wigner function of the squeezed vacuum state,
\begin{align}
W(\alpha,\alpha^*)& =(2/{\pi})\times{e^{-2|\alpha'|^{2}}}\\
 \alpha'& =\alpha \cosh{r}-\alpha^{*}e^{i\theta}\sinh{r} 
\tag 1
\end{align}
I came across the expression in [arXiv:quant-ph/0612024](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0612024). I have so far been able to get to the Husimi $Q$-function of the squeezed vacuum state,
$$
Q(\beta,\beta^*)=(\pi \cosh r)^{-1}e^{-|\beta|^{2}-\tanh(r)/2(e^{i\theta}(\beta^*)^{2}+e^{-i\theta}(\beta)^{2})}
\tag 2
$$
I am trying to get the characteristic antinormal function,
$$
C_{A}(\lambda,\lambda^*)= \int Q(\beta,\beta^*)e^{\lambda\beta^{*}-\lambda^{*}\beta}d^{2}\beta
\tag 3
$$
after which I intend to get the Characteristic Wigner function
$$
C_{W}(\lambda,\lambda^*)=C_{A}e^{|\lambda|^{2}/2}
\tag 4
$$
From which I can get to the Wigner function,
$$
W(\alpha,\alpha^*)=\int C_{W}*e^{\lambda^*\alpha-\lambda\alpha^*}d^{2}\lambda
\tag 5
$$
I am stuck at (3). I have tried expressing the complex variables as
$$
\beta=\frac{q+ip}{\sqrt 2}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\lambda=\frac{x+iy}{\sqrt 2}
\tag 6
$$
and transforming the integral into 2D integral in real coordinates to no avail. I am unable to get a result with which I can proceed further. Is there any other way to deal with 2D Fourier transforms of complex gaussian distributions of the form in $(3)$?

PS: I have just stared learning quantum mechanics this semester along with Quantum optics and have zero formal knowledge of group theory.

Comment: There is a text by Wolfgang Schleich you might like, and one by Ulf Leonhardt.

Comment: For further MathJax (LaTeX) tips, there is a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: @CosmasZachos The texts deal with the distributions in phase space, I need a coherent space picture of the discussion. I am stuck at evaluating the 2-D Fourier Transform of the complex Gaussian distribution, how do I go about that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution#Characteristic_functions